# How to sum up values from last Monday to Now?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column that totals earning, B4:B, which sums up all values, however, I just want it to total values from last (most recent) Monday to Now, until it's Monday again, start over, the date column is A4:A.

I've tried;

> =SUMIF(A4:A,">="&(DATEDIF(ARRAYFORMULA(A4:A),TODAY(),"D"),B4:C)")))")

Comment: Please define last Monday more clearly. Suppose today is Wednesday. Does last Monday means Monday of this week? Or Monday of last week? Or the latest date in column A that's a Monday, regardless of how far back it is?

Comment: If today is Wednesday, then last 2 days on. If today is Monday, today on. If today is Sunday, last possible Monday on. (Monday may not always be there, if that's the case it would be the last tuesday)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=sumif(A4:A,">" & (today()-weekday(today(),3)),B4:B)
```

where `weekday(today(),3)` gives you the weekday where Monday = 0 and Sunday = 6